# Ошибка при запуске Perl: can't locate XML/writer.pm

Tags: perl

> `can't locate XML/writer.pm in @INC <@INC contains: C:\Perl\site\lib c:\Perl\lib .> at C\perl\site\lib\1.pl line 5`

5-я строчка моего кода: use XML::Writer;

Подскажите, как решить проблему.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo cpan XML::Writer
```

или

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e "install XML::Writer"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cpan XML::Writer
```

Answer (score 1):

похоже на ActiveState Perl, тогда еще вариант:

> ppm XML::Writer